# Java Servlet to run on Apache Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to write a Java Servlet with doGet method on Eclipse to determine (with a http request) if a given year is leap or not.
I wrote this simple Java code that does this

```
public class LeapYear { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    boolean isLeapYear;

    // divisible by 4
    isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0);

    // divisible by 4 and not 100
    isLeapYear = isLeapYear && (year % 100 != 0);

    // divisible by 4 and not 100 unless divisible by 400
    isLeapYear = isLeapYear || (year % 400 == 0);

    System.out.println(isLeapYear);
   }
}
```

How do i make this into a Servlet that works on Apache Tomcat 8.5?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched for how to write a servlet?  There are many tutorials.

Comment: yes, there is. But this particular one , i can't understand

Comment: Your question is too broadly scoped. You're asking us to show you how to set up a servlet container. Just follow a tutorial.